# Matrix derivatives for the HJB and ARE relationship

Tags: matrices, derivatives

How does one take the derivative of these matrix equations? (Backround:{My professor used them in the proof showing that the Hamilton-Jacobi-equation equivalently solves the free end-point optimization problem}})

I need help solving these problem,

Show:

1. $ \dfrac{d}{du} \left(u^{T}u\right)=2u$
2. For $k(t)=k^{T}(t)$ we have that $\dfrac{d}{dt} \left(x^{T}k(t)x\right)=2k(t)x$